# 滅多にお目にかからない機能のチェックはどうしますか?

Tags: 討議, プライベートベータ

興味本位で[サイトのJavaScript](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.ja.js?v=5246c4f85f79)を読んでいたら、未翻訳の文字列や、今まで見たことがない機能についての文言があるのに気付きました。

例1:

```
"Favoriting isn't available in read-only mode."
```

これをプライベートベータユーザーが確認するには、運営側でサイトを読み取り専用モードにする必要があります (よね)。

例2:

```
$("<span><b>簡易回答がコメントに変換されました</b></span>");
```

これは私は今まで見たことがない機能です。アドホックなチェックでは、翻訳の確認漏れが出ると思われます。(確認する人数にもよりますが)

考えられる選択肢としては:

1. 機能一覧をプライベートベータユーザーに公開し、1つずつチェックする
2. アドホックな翻訳チェックでokとする

Comment: 技術面では下名が判断できないため、開発者に聞いてみます。見たことない機能はモデレーター関連が多く、そして低品質の質問・ユーザーに関してのチェックも多いです。JSで公開になっているならちょっと問題ですので、聞いてみます。